# Unable to sort queryset by country__name

Tags: django, django-countries

I'm using [django-countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries#the-country-object) to set a country in my django model:

```
# models.py
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    country = CountryField()
```

I would like a have a queryset ordered by `country.name`, but apparently the following queryset:

`MyModel.objects.live().order_by('country__name')`

does not work:

`Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Join on 'country' not permitted.`

Further it is - apparently - not possible to use the model `Meta` option `ordering`.

I could get it ordered in the template by: 
`{% for item in items.all|dictsort:"country.name" %}`
but would prefer to get this done in the queryset.

Did you, dear internet, are aware of a way to get this queryset orderd by `country.name`?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of `MyModel`, is `country` a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: It looks to me, that `Country` is not a model, hence querying in such way, is - at least not by default - enabled.

Comment: It is in fact - behind the curtains - a simple `CharField`, that stores country codes, so this makes it impossible to do this directly.

Comment: Hm, that's what I feared ;-) Are there no ways around this - like annotating the queryset with the ``country.name``?

Comment: not unless you make some sort of model yourself that maps these two-char elements to country names. The point is that the database only stores the two-char code, like `'us'`, `uk'`, `'de'`. So it does not know what the names of the countries are at all. For the database, those are only 2-char strings.

Comment: Ok, that would be overkill in my case, as I successfully sorted this in the template via ``dictsort``.